# How to build libboost_thread_vc100-mt-1_62.lib?

Tags: c++, boost, b2

I'm doing the following but still unable to get libboost_thread_vc100-mt-1_62.lib (Multi threaded library).

```
b2.exe link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared --with-regex --with-thread --with-chrono --toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64
```

The above builds the dll, but the lib file is named as 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib'.

```
b2.exe link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static --with-regex --with-thread --with-chrono --toolset=msvc-10.0 address-model=64  --build-type=complete
```

This builds the static library with the name (libboost_thread-vc100-mt-s-1_62.lib)

I'm looking for libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib. How to build the same?

Comment: It is not clear what is happening. AFAIU, you have successfully built the `.dll`, but you cannot find its `.lib`?

Comment: The lib is with the name 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib'.

Comment: Looking for the file libboost_thread_vc100-mt-1_62.lib.

Comment: This is from memory, but I recall b2 places them in the same output folder.

Comment: have you tried changing the runtime-link from 'static' to 'shared'? The s in the name may stands for this.

Comment: `link=shared`  should build both `.lib` and `.dll` files. Are you sure it doesn't do this?

Comment: link=shared builds 'boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib' but looking for 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib'.

Comment: I think `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib` is a wrong library name and boost will not build a library with this name. If you for some reason need it, copy `boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib` to `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib` (and `boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.dll` to `libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.dll`). Or **maybe** `b2 install` will do the copying/renaming for you, check it out, I'm not quite sure.

Comment: From the Boost manual: *Prefix: except on Microsoft Windows, every Boost library name begins with this string. On Windows, only ordinary static libraries use the lib prefix; import libraries and DLLs do not.*

Comment: As of now, I'm renaming boost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib to libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_62.lib. Let me see if I'm successful in building my application and running the same.